# Issues accessing Control Panel with iPad on iOS 7

Tags: control-panel

I'm having issues accessing the Control Panel using an iPad on iOS 7.0.4. When loading the Dashboard and any subsequent pages, 6 popup alerts will appear with the message:

```
Safari cannot open this page because the address is invalid
```

After dismissing this alert 6 times, it'll disappear until you visit another CP page. I can confirm that there are no issues using iOS 8.1.2. I've tested on numerous sites without any plugins installed, along with a brand new [Craft Demo site](https://demo.buildwithcraft.com/), and the issue persists.

[image]

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: Tried googling without much luck, but what version of Safari is bundled with iOS 7.0.4?

Comment: Just busted out the Xcode simulator for 7.1, same issue.  ``User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 7_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11D167 Safari/9537.53``

Comment: On other pages, the dialog doesn't come up as often; e.g. on settings, it only comes up twice.  I think something in garnish is trying to call about:blank which Safari isn't happy about....

Comment: As noted in [your answer](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/11301/45), this was a bug (which has since been resolved). Closing as a "bug report".

Answer (score 1):

As @RitterKnight points out, it does seem to be an issue with Garnish. I've managed to narrow it down to garnish-0.1.js:1020, which is to do with resize detection as adapted from http://www.backalleycoder.com/2013/03/18/cross-browser-event-based-element-resize-detection/

As one of the [comments](http://fyre.it/tRMZHE.4) points out, changing the following line fixes the issue:

```
var obj = elem.__resizeTrigger__ = document.createElement('object');
to
var obj = elem.__resizeTrigger__ = document.createElement('iframe');
```

I'm not sure if this has any adverse effects on anything else, so would be keen to see if this is something already tested by the P&T team.

**EDIT:** This has now been fixed in [Craft 2.4.2691](http://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2691).